# logic for Custom Start Day and End Day for a week. (c#)

Tags: c#

We have a unique requirment where we have our own start day of a week and end day of a week(C#),

Contrary to the existing Date Time class whose start day is Sunday and end day is Saturday, we have Wednesday as our start day and Tuesday our EndDay (and this will vary per client).

and we need to implement the following logic

a) for a given date get the start Date of a week and end Date of a week

Ex: based on the above if the current day is  23/Sep/2010 (Thur) we need to get  22/Sep/2010 (Wed) as our Start Day and 28/Sep/2010 (Tue) as our end day

i apologize there is a correction the end day should be Tuesday (7 days a week)

Can anyone help here?

Thanks

Comment: How about creating an Extension method that adds a configurable number of days to the existing DateTime class?

Comment: There is no Tuesday, there is only your idea of Tuesday, which has been embedded into your mind from the matrix. Accept it, and move on.

Comment: can you free my mind Jordao ... (Morpheus)???

Comment: Ah, I get it then, Nen wants to build a new matrix.... if only his name was Neo....

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you just do

```
(dt.DayOfWeek + delta) % 7
```

?

Comment: i dont quiet understand what is delta here?

Comment: delta is how many days from Sunday to your arbitrary start of week day.  So if your start of week is Wednesday, your delta would be 3 (Sun + 3 days is Wed)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my inelegant crack at it:

```
public static void CalculateWeek (out DateTime WeekStart, out DateTime WeekEnd, DateTime InputDate)
    {
        DateTime tempDT = InputDate;

        while (tempDT.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Wednesday)
        {
            tempDT = tempDT.AddDays(-1);
        }

        WeekStart = tempDT.Date;

        while (tempDT.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Tuesday)
        {
            tempDT = tempDT.AddDays(1);
        }

        WeekEnd = tempDT.Date;
    }
```

By no means clever or superefficient, although the loops will iterate no more than a trivial 7 times.